# Unable to parse JSON object using Volley

Tags: android, json, android-volley

JSON file:

[JSON FILE URL](http://cipherads.co.in/api/bbps/billers/billers.json)

i am looping through the "biller" Array to fetch all the object's where "billerCategory": is 
 "Electricity". I am trying to get "paramName" value. But i am only getting 3 paramName values.

Response:

Code:

```
try {
                JSONArray biller = response.getJSONArray("biller");

                Log.d(TAG, biller.toString());

                // Loop through biller Array and find billerID
                for (int i = 0; i < biller.length(); i++)
                {
                    JSONObject billerObj = (JSONObject) biller.get(i);
                    String category = billerObj.getString("billerCategory");


                    //Log.d(TAG, category);

                    if (category.equalsIgnoreCase("Electricity")){

                        JSONObject paraminput = billerObj.getJSONObject("billerInputParams");
                        JSONObject paramInfo = paraminput.getJSONObject("paramInfo");
                        String paramName = paramInfo.getString("paramName");


                        Log.d(TAG, paramName);

                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Can't be reproduced, dead link.

Answer (score 0):

An exception has occured. Search for 'TORR00000SUR04'. It happened that "paramInfo" is an JSONArray at that point.

Comment: what is a possible resolution for this ?

Comment: Use 2 x try-catch-exception for both conditions below, and one will succeed.

    JSONObject paramInfoObject = paraminput.getJSONObject("paramInfo");

    JSONArray paramInfoArray = paraminput.getJSONArray("paramInfo");

Comment: This is not an answer but seems more like a comment. Please see Stack Overflow [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help) how to answer section.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Thanks for the heads-up. New user at that time, wasn't aware of the 'add a comment' link. Just fill the big blank box which happens to be the 'Answer' field.